# Уникальное всплывающее окно в таблице

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нуждаюсь в помощи, сам не знаю js и обычно копирую существующий код.
У меня есть таблица, которая заполняется из БД, в конце каждой строки есть кнопка для редактирования записи. При нажатии открывается диалоговое окно с уже заполненными данными, проблема только состоит в том,
что диалоговое окно открывается только на первой строке.
Я знаю что проблема состоит в том, что диалоговое окно открывается по ID кнопки, и из-за того что записи дублируются ID остается тот же, но как говорил ранее js не знаю. Помогите исправить, кому не сложно, буду благодарен.

**Код:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - HTML 5.2 new dialog tag</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:200,400,700'><link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<!-- Simple boîte de dialogue, contenant un formulaire -->
<dialog id="favDialog">
  <form method="dialog">
    <section>
      <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="age" id="age"><br><br>
    </section>
    <menu>
      <button id="cancel" type="reset">reset</button>
      <button id="submit" type="submit">submit</button>
    </menu>
  </form>
</dialog>

<table id="table" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>settings</th>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td>FN1</td>
                <td>LN1</td>
                <td>111</td>
                <td><a id="updateDetails">edit(нажми на меня)</a></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td>FN2</td>
                <td>LN2</td>
                <td>211</td>
                <td><a id="updateDetails">edit</a></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td>FN3</td>
                <td>LN3</td>
                <td>311</td>
                <td><a id="updateDetails">edit</a></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td>FN4</td>
                <td>LN4</td>
                <td>411</td>
               <td><a id="updateDetails">edit</a></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td>FN5</td>
                <td>LN5</td>
                <td>511</td>
                 <td><a id="updateDetails">edit</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
  

<!-- partial -->
  <script  src="./script.js"></script>
      <script>
    
                var table = document.getElementById('table');
                
                for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
                {
                    table.rows[i].onclick = function()
                    {
                         //rIndex = this.rowIndex;
                         document.getElementById("fname").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
                         document.getElementById("lname").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
                         document.getElementById("age").value = this.cells[2].innerHTML;
                    };
                }
    
         </script>

</body>
</html>
```

https://codepen.io/kolya-geshko/pen/rNWRKEo

Comment: Смотрите полный код на Codepen по ссылке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю как-то так, можно сделать.

я подправил

```
var updateButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('updateDetails');
```

потому что у вас несколько элементов с идентификатором `updateDetails`

```js
(function() {
    var updateButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('updateDetails');
    var cancelButton = document.getElementById('cancel');
        var submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');

    // Update button opens a modal dialog
    [...updateButtons].forEach(updateButton => updateButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      document.getElementById('favDialog').showModal();
    }));

    // Bouton pour fermer la boîte de dialogue
    cancelButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      document.getElementById('favDialog').close();
    });

    // Bouton pour fermer la boîte de dialogue
    submitButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      // тут обновите сами
    });

  })();
```

```css
* {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

dialog#favDialog::backdrop {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(207, 161, 252, 0.6) 0%, rgba(113, 102, 240, 0.6) 100%);
}

menu.card {
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 480px;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 100px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
menu.card p {
  color: #444;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

button {
  background: #7367F0;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #CE9FFC 0%, #7367F0 100%);
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 100px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border: none;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 500ms ease;
}
button:hover {
  background: #CE9FFC;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #CE9FFC 0%, #CE9FFC 100%);
}
button#cancel {
  background: #E3E3E3;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #E3E3E3 0%, #5D6874 100%);
}
button#cancel:hover {
  background: #5D6874;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #E3E3E3 0%, #E3E3E3 100%);
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - HTML 5.2 new dialog tag</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:200,400,700'><link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<!-- Simple boîte de dialogue, contenant un formulaire -->
<dialog id="favDialog">
  <form method="dialog">
    <section>
      <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="age" id="age"><br><br>
    </section>
    <menu>
      <button id="cancel" type="reset">reset</button>
      <button id="submit" type="submit">submit</button>
    </menu>
  </form>
</dialog>

<table id="table" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>settings</th>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td>FN1</td>
                <td>LN1</td>
                <td>111</td>
                <td><a class="updateDetails">edit(нажми на меня)</a></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td>FN2</td>
                <td>LN2</td>
                <td>211</td>
                <td><a class="updateDetails">edit</a></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td>FN3</td>
                <td>LN3</td>
                <td>311</td>
                <td><a class="updateDetails">edit</a></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td>FN4</td>
                <td>LN4</td>
                <td>411</td>
               <td><a class="updateDetails">edit</a></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td>FN5</td>
                <td>LN5</td>
                <td>511</td>
                 <td><a class="updateDetails">edit</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
  

<!-- partial -->
  <script  src="./script.js"></script>
      <script>
    
                var table = document.getElementById('table');
                [...table.rows].forEach((row, index)=>{
                 if (index > 0) {                   
                 row.addEventListener("click", function()
                    {
                         document.getElementById("fname").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
                         document.getElementById("lname").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
                         document.getElementById("age").value = this.cells[2].innerHTML;
                    });
                  }
                });
        
                
        
    
         </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!